# Adding intervals as part of an SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, etl

Very long shot here as Im not sure this is possible - if it is then I definitely owe you guys.

I have a table with start_date, end_date and hours. Consider I have one line of start_date 1 Jan 2015, end_date of 31 Dec 2015 and hours as 120.
I want to produce a result of 12 lines with 10 hours in each line and the month

so something like

```
|Jan 15|10|
|Feb 15|10|
...
|Dec 15|10|
```

I want ten because I am dividing 120 hours by the number of months (12). 120 / 12 = 10

Can I do this at all? Or anything similar? I suspect I may have to do ETL in code rather than in SQL. Has anyone got any ideas on how I could anything to get closer to what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a numbers tables.  If you had one, you could do:

```
select add_months(start_date, n.n - 1),
       val / (months_between(start_date, end_date) + 1)
from t join
     numbers n
     on add_months(start_date, n.n - 1) <= end_date;
```

You can create a `numbers` table in various ways.  An easy way is something like this:

```
with numbers as (
      select rownum as n
      from t
      where rownum <= 100
     )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @gordonlinoff. If I create the number table with the "with..." will it create it just for this transaction? Im want o run this SQL on a prod database so dont want to affect this. Thanks

Comment: The `rownum` trick here is one [row generator technique](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques) for Oracle. These techniques do not create real tables in the database, only temporary data sets which you can use as a part of your main query. Perhaps @Gordon could edit the answer to include a complete query with the row generator?